# Ember Controller lifecycle hooks

Tags: ember.js

I know there is an `init` hook but it seems that the view it not setup properly at that stage.  I need to hook into the event once the screen is setup properly from the controller.

Where is the documentation on all the controller and route lifecylce hooks.  I found the ones for the View only:

```
didInsertElement 
parentViewDidChange 
willClearRender 
willDestroyElement 
willInsertElement
```

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do? The "screen being setup properly" is view-specific, so that's the `didInsertElement` hook on the view. A route has the standard, well-document lifecycle hooks such as `model`, `beforeModel`, `afterModel`, and `setupController.` A controller does not have, or need, lifecycle hooks other than `init`. What else do you want to do?

Comment: @torazaburo ok, I assumed there would be more than that.

Comment: The controller is a Singleton and so any other lifecycle event other than init won't make sense.

Answer (score 9):

In ember controllers lifecycle is not very clearly defined as the controller does not serve much purpose other than making the variables available to the template.

Controller has few hooks 2 of them are

1. *init* - initialise with default values, its called only once.
2. *willDestroy* - hook for any view teardown

Router hooks can be of two types when you enter in the route and when you leave it.

Router hooks

**Startup Hooks**

1. beforeModel
2. model
3. afterModel
4. redirect
5. activate
6. setupController
7. renderTemplate

**Shutdown Hooks**

1. deactivate
2. resetController

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `didInsertElement` in the the view. It is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM element is inserted in the page.

Note that, only the view (root element) is guaranteed to be inserted and if you are planning to add events or DOM manipulations for that view, you have to use the `afterRenderEvent` technique. Read the [afterRenderEvent technique](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/). The mixin I use: [after render mixin](https://gist.github.com/givanse/0cea6a415efed18be5a7).

Edit:
Since 1.8.0-beta.1 the `didInsertElement` has changed and it waits until it fires in the last child of the view and then bubbles up from there. The after render mixin is no longer necessary.